# Panel content page not displaying correctly after restoring backup on different server

Tags: theming, backups

I recently had to restore a backup to a new server, and many things seem to be working fine, but others are not. For example The panes page which is suppose to show links neatly on the page in a dropdown menu is displaying them messily around the page. My pixture reloaded theme is also not working correctly.It doesn't seem to have the css styling.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Hi you should check the folders for the correct permissions :)

Answer (score 0):

First, before doing anything else, try clearing all the Drupal caches.

Then, if that doesn't do the trick, you need to make sure that you restore your files as well as your database.  Adaptivetheme and Panels both save some of their settings in files (for example, Adaptivetheme saves the color information of the theme); if you restore the database without the files, your site will behave strangely until you restore the files as well.

Alternately, if for some reason you do not have a copy of the files, you can re-save the theme settings by going to Appearance -> Theme name -> and then scrolling down to the bottom of the page and clicking "Save," which will cause Drupal to regenerate the theme files.

Comment: Thanks, I restored the adaptivetheme files and I was able to recover the pixture reloaded theme.  However I still the word messy displayed in the panes page and in the settings page for the theme. I am not sure why this is happening. I cleared all caches by going into Configuration>Performance> Clear All Caches, but that didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: You'll have to re-save the admin theme too in the same manner (that's where the Panels CSS is).

Comment: Hi Patrick, I tried that, but it didn't seem to help. I just added a picture of what my panels content looks like to give a better description of my problem.